# iOS7 storyboard in Xcode 5 keep growing vertically

Tags: storyboard, ios7, xcode5

After clicking on an iPad storyboard in Xcode 5, it asked if I want to upgrade to iOS7 storyboard.  While the alert is on the screen, it keeps growing the view controllers vertically.  the "growing" stops after you select "upgrade", but by that time the damage is done and the size of the view controllers have increased.

Any way to fix this annoying problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ok, I found a work-around:

1. commit a version of your code before Xcode changes its storyboard (we will get back  to this version)
2. click on the storyboard.  Xcode will ask if you want to upgrade.
3. Choose the "always upgrade" button (I forget the actual text of the button)
4. at this state the storyboard is already messed up by Xcode.  don't worry. just close the project.
5. do a "git stash" and go back to the version to committed in step 0 above
6. open your project again.

now Xcode has upgraded your storyboard without distorting it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This drove me crazy. How could you find out the way to  solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found it also helps to choose "iPad Full Screen" for "Size" of the View Controller instead of "Freeform". It seems to snap the size to 1024x768 and not let it change.