# Looking for a tutorial on moving Pre-Storyboard code (XCode4) to Storyboard code (XCode5)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to get to grips with XCode5, but most code samples are pre-XCode5. and of course pre iOS7. The main issue is Storyboards. LOTS of people want to know how to build in SCode5 without Storyboards - but I wan't to know how to move pre-storyboard code to storyboard code.

For Example. The most excellent book, "Geolocation in iOS" Alasdair Allan, O'Reilly, 2012, is full of code written a few releases ago. Of course as I am coming into XCode at XCode5/iOS7 level, I have no idea what they are talking about in various parts. 
I kind of have the beginning of the sample code working but it's throwing an erro now and I can't figure it out. I suspect because its trying to do it Code4 way, and I'm in XCode5.

Anyway - what would be nice is a tutorial that points out what one changes.
Let me give an example:
The code for the first example in the book goes like this.

In the Project Navigator image in the book, it shows

```
LocationAppDelegate.h
LocationAppDelegate.m
LocationViewController.h
LocationViewController.
LocationViewController.xib
```

In my display, I have all the same files, Except. Instead of the ".xib" file I have "Main.storyboard"

So far ok - I believe from what I have read, that the Main.storyboard is the new equivelant of the xib file.
But there are a LOT of differences in the automatically generated code within the .h and .m files. So having done my best, I at least have the location service displaying a dummy location in the debug window.

But - now I have this error. Well two errors actually.

**The first, a Semantic warning**

```
LocationViewController.m:15:17: Method 'tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:' in protocol not implemented
```

**The second, an error with the red ! mark**

```
LocationViewController.m:60:9: No visible @interface for 'UITableView' declares the selector 'dequeueReusableCellWithIndentifier:'
```

The code as it appears in the book is fairly straight forward, but this error has lost me.

**The code from LocationViewController.m**

```
//
//  LocationViewController.h
//  Location
//
//  Created by Robert Chalmers on 08/10/2013.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Robert Chalmers. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface LocationViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@end
```

**The code from LocationViewController.m**

```
//
//  LocationViewController.m
//  Location
//
//  Created by Robert Chalmers on 08/10/2013.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Robert Chalmers. All rights reserved.
//

#import "LocationViewController.h"

@interface LocationViewController ()

@end

@implementation LocationViewController

@synthesize tableView = _tableView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle






#pragma mark UITableViewDelegate Methods

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tv
        didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //add code here
}

#pragma mark UITableViewDataSource Methods

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tv {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tv numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 5;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *identifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell =
    //[tv dequeueReusableCellWithIndentifier:@"cell"];
    [tv dequeueReusableCellWithIndentifier:@"cell"];
    if (cell == nil ) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                       reuseIdentifier:identifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    return cell;
    }

}



@end
```

and for what it's worth, the code from LocationAppDelegate.h and followed by .m

```
//
//  LocationAppDelegate.h
//  Location
//
//  Created by Robert Chalmers on 08/10/2013.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Robert Chalmers. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class viewController;

@interface LocationAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) viewController *viewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

@end




============

//
//  LocationAppDelegate.m
//  Location
//
//  Created by Robert Chalmers on 08/10/2013.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Robert Chalmers. All rights reserved.
//

#import "LocationAppDelegate.h"
#import "LocationViewController.h"

@implementation LocationAppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize viewController = _viewController;
@synthesize locationManager = _locationManager;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {
        self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        self.locationManager.delegate = self;
        self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 1000;
        [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }

    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
                         didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
                          fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
                              NSLog(@"Location: %@", [newLocation description]);
                          }

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
       didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error description]);
}




@end
```

Mostly of course, I'd like to know what that error is, but also if there is some guidelines as to what now goes in what files?

Thanks.

Comment: The storyboard is like a collection of all xibs. You can probably just select your views inside your xib and copy paste them to the storyboard. Then connect all the connections to your viewcontroller again. The transfer takes a shitload of time, but there won't be a fast way to transfer from xib to storyboard otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can find your answer
[iOS7 storyboard in Xcode 5 keep growing vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907772/ios7-storyboard-in-xcode-5-keep-growing-vertically)

- Commit a version of your code before Xcode changes its storyboard

  - Click on the storyboard. Xcode will ask if you want to upgrade.
  - Choose the always upgrade
  - At this state the storyboard is already messed up by Xcode. don't
    worry. just close the project.
  - Do a "git stash" and go back to the version to committed in step 0
    above
  - Open your project again.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have a look into [this](http://lifeandcode.net/2013/07/fixing-xcode-5-dp3-storyboard-could-not-be-opened-verify-document-content-error/) to fix xcode 5 storyboards errors.

Regarding the error, you should try:

```
[tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Instead of:

```
[tv dequeueReusableCellWithIndentifier:@"cell"];
```

Comment: **Thanks to everyone** - Awesome amount of trouble just to move code in a text book into the new version. Keeping it all in mind, that it can be done that is, I think I'll just stay with XCode5 and iOS7 material from here on in. Just not worth the headaches trying to move old code to new platform.

Comment: However, did you manage to fix the error _No visible interface for 'UITableView' declares the selector 'dequeueReusableCellWithIndentifier:'_ ? @Robert.C

Comment: Yes. I did. Just my usual lack of spelling ability. Plus some code that someone helped me with. Code I had was depreciated, and the new code fixed it. It was like one word different. unbelievable.

Comment: Im glad you fixed it. If my answer helped you somehow, feel free to accept it: [how to accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)